# If $\sum_{i=k}^n {n \choose i} p^{i}(1-p)^{n-i} \approx 0.05$, how can we find $k$?

Tags: probability, statistics, approximation, binomial-distribution, algebraic-equations

Let $n$ be any natural number, let $k\in\{0, \dots, n\}$, and let $p \in [0, 1]$.

If $\sum_{i=k}^n {n \choose i} p^{i}(1-p)^{n-i} \approx 0.05$, how can we find $k$ (in terms of $n$ and $p$)?

Comment: See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_bounds) on wikipedia.

Comment: Without more information on the magnitudes of $n$ and $p$, there is not much better that you can do than summing the terms explicitly, starting from $i=n$.

Comment: What is the context of your question?

Comment: You could approximate this binomial process by a normal, for which the equivalent problem is considerably easier.  If more precise answers are needed, at least this gives you a good starting point.

Comment: While software could give you exact answers, binomial tables are also available if you are looking for an approximate answer. The solution may be even simpler depending on $n$ and $p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some cases you can use a normal approximation with continuity correction and say $$\Phi\left(\frac{k-0.5 - np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\right) \approx 1-0.05$$

Since $\Phi(1.644854) \approx 0.95$ you could then say in these cases $$k \approx np+0.5+ 1.644854\sqrt{np(1-p)}$$

As an example, suppose $n=40$ and $p=\frac14$.  Then this suggests $k \approx 15$

As a check  $\sum\limits_{i=15}^{40} {40 \choose i} \left(\frac14\right)^i\left(\frac34\right)^{40-i} \approx 0.054$ so this is not a bad approximation; $k=14$ would give about $0.103$ while $k=16$ would give about $0.026$